# how to store date value using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

```
  @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date docDate;
  public Date getDocDate() {
    return docDate;
}
public void setDocDate(Date docDate) {
    this.docDate = docDate;
}
```

but the error shows like this

```
Error setting expression 'docDate' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@843f72'
ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "setDocDate" failed for object net.top.app.entity.document.Document@291a66 [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.top.app.entity.document.Document_$$_javassist_4.setDocDate([Ljava.lang.String;)]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1285)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1474)
```

Comment: Whats the SQL type of the `docDate` column?

Comment: docDate column type is Date

Comment: which version of Ognl using

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to pass a String to `setDocDate()`. Change it so as to pass a Date.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Error , `setDocDate()` is having Date field as input type.

You are setting the `docDate` in UI it self, try to convert the field to Date and set it to `docDate`

Comment: i am also use date value     entity.setDocDate(new Date());     but it show same error